# Pandas - set value in row to itself multiplied by another value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following table:

```
multiply   total   tax
Y          500     .1
Y          250     .5
N          300     .5
```

I want to set the total to total * tax only if the value of multiply is Y

Final output:

```
multiply   total   tax
Y          50      .1
Y          125     .5
N          300     .5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `np.where`

```
df['total'] = np.where(df['multiply'] == 'Y', df['total'] * df['tax'], df['total'])
print(df)

multiply  total  tax
       Y   50.0  0.1
       Y  125.0  0.5
       N  300.0  0.5
```

Comment: Clean. Worked beautifully

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like that

```
df.loc[df['multiply'] == 'Y', 'total'] = df.loc[df['multiply'] == 'Y', 'total'] * df.loc[df['multiply'] == 'Y', 'tax']
```

Another approach using pandas [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) could be:

```
df.where(df['multiply'] == 'N', df.assign(total = df['total'] * df['tax']))
```

Outputs:

```
    multiply    total   tax
0   Y           50      0.1
1   Y           125     0.5
2   N           300     0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

here we go buddy

```
df.loc[df.multiply == 'Y', 'total'] = df.loc[df.multiply == 'Y', 'total'] * df.loc[df.multiply == 'Y', 'tax']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'multiply':['Y','Y','N'],'total':[500,250,300],'tax':[.1,.5,.5]})
def myfunc(row):
    if(row[0]=='Y'):
        return float(row[1])*float(row[2])
    return row[2]
df['total']=df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x),axis=1)
df
```

Output

```
multiply   tax  total
0   Y      0.1  50.0
1   Y      0.5  125.0
2   N      0.5  300.0
```

Comment: this will not scale well for large frames